# How to add bulleted list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am unable to add bullet in front of any sentence.

See below example, I need circle bullets in front of every sentence written in one cell.

- First Sentence
- Second Sentence
- Third Sentence

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Google Sheets does not support bulleted lists.

The shortcut used for Google Docs (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>) has no effect in Google Sheets.

Further, copy-pasting bulleted text from elsewhere into Google Sheets removes the bullets.

The closest I've found is to manually insert the round bullet character. In Windows, the code to enter that character is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> (using the keypad). That results in a •. There are other characters you can use instead, of course.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, press Alt + 7. This ONLY works with the 7 on the numeric keypad, and not the 7 on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN add a bullet point list within a cell in Google Sheets. 
Using a MAC:

1. Double-click on the cell
2. Click: OPTION + 8 and a bullet will appear, type your information
3. Click: CONTROL + ENTER/RETURN to move to the next line within the cell
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3 for all bullets you want within the same cell
5. Hit ENTER or TAB when finished to move into a new cell

When using a PC, I think you use <kbd>alt</kbd> + 0149 instead of Option + 8.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've always struggled to do such a seemingly simple task.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Google Drawings, as well as Google Sheets, you can add a square bullet by going to:

`Insert`, selecting `Drawing`, and then click on the `Shape` icon.
Select `Shapes` in the drop-down window and create the desired shape.
Select `Save and Close`, and then position and resize the image as needed.

The downside to this feature, however, is that you will have to repeat this action for each cell.
You cannot copy and paste a drawing into other cells.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQtBneJEGKk 
Basically you could just **use a dash (-) to mark your bullet and then ctrl+enter changes rows**, so that's as far as lists are supported within a Sheets cell what I've found out

Answer (score -1):

On a Mac, press <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>. That will insert a bullet point.

Comment: Note that the question is about Google _Sheets_. <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> does not seem to work there.